# display Multidimensional Arrays android

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using android studio and with opencv 3.4.0. I want to display a Multidimensional Array in text view. I have an a array "candidats_result" and I copied her values into a Multidimensional array  " finale". after runing my code I got this result in emulator [display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA3hE.png). what I have to change in my code to get the text displayed

```
double [][] R_finale = new double[20][20];

                    int ZZ = 0;
                    int ZE = 0;
                    int EE = 0;

                    for(int i=0;i<19;i++){
                      for(int j=0;j<19;j++){
                        R_finale[i][j] = candidats_result[ZZ];
                          ZZ++;
                      }
                    }

                 String [][] finale = new String [20][20];
                //showing the array in android
                for(int i=0;i<19;i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
                        finale[i][j] = Double.toString(R_finale[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                String [][] details = new String[20][20];
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for ( int i = 0 ; i<20;i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                        details[i][j] = String.valueOf(R_finale [i][j]);
                        builder.append(details + ";");
                    }
                }


                textView.setText(String.valueOf(builder));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice below lines:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i<20;i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
           details[i][j] = String.valueOf(R_finale [i][j]);
           builder.append(details + ";"); //should be builder.append(details[i][j] + ";");
         }
}
```